# Does a skill at d4-2 count for the wild die too?

Tags: savage-worlds

I've seen that with skills with a +x bonus, it applies to both the skill die and the wild die.  How about if you have an untrained skill at d4-2.  Does the -2 also apply to your wild die?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. Savage Worlds,

- Revised Edition, Page 57
- Explorer Edition, Page 56
- Deluxe Edition, Page 63.

> Wild Card
>   characters still get their Wild Die for these
>   rolls (which are also subject to the -2 penalty).

Comment: Thanks!  With all the definite, conflicting answers around the table, I'd come to assume it wasn't in the rule book.

Comment: Glad to be of help.